# Proper rel attribute value for print view link iaw HTML5

Tags: html, printing, rel

I started to design my site consistent with HTML5 (semi) standards.

I have a link as:

`<a href="#" title="Print View" rel="">Print View</a>`

My site is PHP driven and this link opens a page which I can not create it with pure css. (additional content exists on print view page). So I must have this link.

I ask for the Proper `rel`  attribute value for print view link

I googled my question but couldn't find any help also I looked to HTML5 Doctor, W3C

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partly depends on what the link really points to, but it seems that it is a version of the current page with some additional information and/or styling for the print media. In that case, the attribute

```
rel="alternate"
```

would seem to be adequate. The definition of [`rel="alternate"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate) is not exact, so it is debatable how much the two documents may differ, when it says “The keyword creates a hyperlink referencing an alternate representation of the current document.”

In practice, the attribute `rel="alternate"` is mostly ignored. It may, or might, be used by search engines to decide that the linked document need not be visited, as its content is basically the same as that of the current document. If that’s OK, you can use it.

By the way, a link text like “Printable version” might be more descriptive. “Print View” sounds like Print Preview, something that you can do with the tools of the browser

Comment: Thank you so much Jukka. +1 for your "Printable version" advice. I'll apply it.